# sed replace number with number-1

Tags: bash, replace, sed, expression-evaluation

Can sed handle a substitution and simultaneously evaluate an expression to substitute somehow?

For example, I have the following entry in a text file:

```
##################################### topd Tree1 - Tree14 #######################################
```

For reasons I won't go in to, each Tree's number is N+1 relative to another numbering scheme I've been using so far.

Could sed (or any util really, sed is just my go to for find-and-replace operations), find every instance of `TreeN` and replace them with `TreeN-1` such that the above line would then look like:

```
##################################### topd Tree0 - Tree13 #######################################
```

(Using Ubuntu 12.02, so pretty much anything goes.)

Comment: If your columns are predictable, `awk` knows math...

Comment: Yeah, you aren't doing this with sed.

Comment: I think they are (there is the same run of ### space, topd.... etc etc, though that seems less robust to me that finding the string?

Comment: `sed` can't do math. You should look into Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using perl

```
perl -pe 's/Tree\K\d+/$&-1/ge' file
```

Output

```
##################################### topd Tree0 - Tree13 #######################################
```

Comment: using perl seems to be the easiest solution.

Comment: Nice, I ended up trying this one first so accepted as the answer. To make it a bit more informative, could you elaborate on which bits of syntax are doing what? I can pick apart elements but not all of it.

Comment: @JoeHealey `\K` cause the replacement to only affect the right hand side, so only the digits `\d+` are matched. `$&` is matched string. `g` is global, as in make as many matches as many as possible. `e` evaluate the replacement part of the regex as though it were a command.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use perl in this case, with the `e` modifier to evaluate an expression in the replacement part:

```
perl -pe 's/(Tree)(\d+)/$1 . ($2 - 1)/ge'
```

You can also take advantage of more advanced regular expression support, e.g. by using a lookbehind assertion:

```
perl -pe 's/(?<=Tree)(\d+)/$1 - 1/ge'
```

Comment: You will want `g` flag as well and no `#`

Comment: @123 yeah I didn't notice that both numbers were supposed to be decremented, edited thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
sed 's/[^0-9,-]*//g' filename | sed -e "s/-/ /g" | awk '{print "##################################### topd Tree"$1-1 " - Tree" $2-1 " #######################################"}'

awk '{gsub(/Tree/,"Tree ",$0);print $1" "$2" "$3$4-1" "$5" "$6$7-1" "$8}' filename
```

Comment: A single awk solution is possible for this. This looks two `sed`s and `awk` seems redundant

Answer (score 0):

Using gnu awk below

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
     $i ~ /^Tree[[:digit:]]+$/
     {
     n=(gensub(/Tree/,"",1,$i)-1);
     $i=gensub(/Tree([[:digit:]]+)/,"Tree"n,1,$i);
     }
     }
     print}' file
```

would do the trick