# Script to increment number in a file

Tags: shell

I have one file like below,let say file name is file1.txt:

```
s.version      = "11.7.10"
```

Here I have to increment the last number by 1, so it should be 1+1=2 like..

```
s.version      = "11.7.11"
```

Is there any way for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This requirement is ambiguous as the version is not simply a floating point number.

Comment: @sjsam I have modified the content,thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to update the revision here?

Comment: @sjsam sorry,i am a new guy,please tell me what should i do,thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sed replace number with number-1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38348547/sed-replace-number-with-number-1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would go with `Perl`, as follows:

```
perl -pe '/s.version/ && s/(\d+)(")/$1+1 . $2/e' file.txt
```

That says... *"On any line where you find "s.version", substitute the last one or more digits followed by a double quote, with whatever those digits were plus one and the double quote"*

So, if your file contains this:

```
fred
s.version      = "11.7.10"
s.version      = "11.7"
s.version="12.99.99"
frog
```

You will get this:

```
fred
s.version      = "11.7.11"
s.version      = "11.8"
s.version="12.99.100"
frog
```

If you want `Perl` to edit the file in-place (i.e. overwrite the input file), you can use the `-i` option:

```
perl -i.orig -pe '/s.version/ && s/(\d+)(")/$1+1 . $2/e' file.txt
```

and then your input file will be overwritten, but a backup saved in `file.txt.orig`

Comment: p cancels out n flag.Also can be more consise `perl -pe 's/s.version.*\K\d+/$&+1/e'`

Comment: @123 Thank you for your insights. I have removed the `-n` flag as you suggested. The `K` syntax is beyond my meagre `Perl` skills and I cannot explain it satisfactorily, so I would prefer not to try and *sell* it as my own! If you want to put it as an answer, I'll be more than happy to up-vote you :-)

Comment: From perlre `\K        [6]  Keep the stuff left of the \K, don't include it in $&`. Feel free to use it in your answer, or not, up to you. I won't be writing an answer though :)